# Do savedinstance in my FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android

In my FragmentActivity i have a recycleView  and i want do save instance in my Activity, because i have a tabLayout with View pager look in the picture
the Question is how can i do save instance to recycle view in my code
please help me

[This is the image of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGsit.png)

### this is my code:

```
   public class Menu1Fragment extends Fragment {
        recycleAdapter imp_listArrayAdapter;
        public static ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
   
        public Menu1Fragment() {
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);
            //if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            //Restore the fragment's state here
            //  }
            //
    
            Boolean a = false;
    
    
            ArrayList<imp_list> impLists = new ArrayList<imp_list>();
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Make a Banana", "3000", R.drawable.makabananasplit, a));
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Abdeys Apple Sizzler", "2000", R.drawable.abbeys, a));
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Cheese Cake", "1000", R.drawable.cheesecake, a));
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Choise Of Ice_Cream", "1500", R.drawable.icecream, a));
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Daeth By Chocolate", "3000", R.drawable.deathbychocolate, a));
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Make a Banana", "3000", R.drawable.makabananasplit, a));
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Abdeys Apple Sizzler", "2000", R.drawable.abbeys, a));
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Cheese Cake", "1000", R.drawable.cheesecake, a));
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Choise Of Ice_Cream", "1500", R.drawable.icecream, a));
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Daeth By Chocolate", "3000", R.drawable.deathbychocolate, a));
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Make a Banana", "3000", R.drawable.makabananasplit, a));
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Abdeys Apple Sizzler", "2000", R.drawable.abbeys, a));
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Cheese Cake", "1000", R.drawable.cheesecake, a));
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Choise Of Ice_Cream", "1500", R.drawable.icecream, a));
            impLists.add(new imp_list("Daeth By Chocolate", "3000", R.drawable.deathbychocolate, a));
    
    
            imp_listArrayAdapter = new recycleAdapter(getActivity(), impLists);
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.res_id);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(imp_listArrayAdapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            arrayList = imp_listArrayAdapter.stringArrayList;
    
    
            return rootView;
    
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Could you please update your question to make it clearer?

Comment: the question is how i can do save instance in my recycleview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` on your `ViewPager` in your activity. Like this it won't destroy the other *(3)* Pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            String something = savedInstanceState.getString("string1");

        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putString("string1","something");
    }
}
```

This will work for orienation change.
If you replace the fragment without putting it in backstack, its state (and saved instance state) will be cleared along with the fragment.

Comment: but how can i do saveInstance in recycleView

Comment: cant get what you are saying.

Comment: by LayoutManager